# best way to eliminate mySQL result column with no value

Tags: mysql

I have a query that dumps a fairly large joined table into a CVS file.  Depending on the input parameters there are circumstances where entire columns wind up being empty. I'm imagining a ham-fisted solution of opening up the CSV file after it's been written, and looping through all the rows, looking for situations where entire columns are empty and then re-writing the file with those columns removed. However, I was hoping there was some shorthand SQL way to not bother to write those columns in the first place.
To complicate things just slightly I have a UNION at the top which lays out the column headers in the CSV... I'd need to omit those as well...

Any takers? :)

Comment: This would lead in future to confusion. I don't recommend. If you will compress the file it will also disappear.

Comment: Yep, edit the question and insert the select statement into the question so we don't have to mindread :-).

Comment: Why do you have a columns that have no values in any of the rows?  Seems pointless.

Comment: There are a lot of shell tools that can help you http://www.novell.com/communities/node/9168/delete-empty-columns-csv-file

Comment: The reason there are sometimes columns that have no rows is that this is a general purpose "users" table, and depending on how you pull the data, there are situations where, for example, no phone_numbers are present. In that case, I need to present the CSV without a phone_number column. As to posting the query, that won't be helpful... everyone knows what a query looks like, and this one is massive and very convoluted.  The question is simply whether it's possible to auto-magically omit an entire column of results if those results are universally null.

Comment: No, it's not possible to auto-filter empty rows. You could perhaps wrap in another SELECT and do some funky WHERE NOT NULL check but I doubt it would make you very happy, for completion sake I'll write an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE NOT NULL` example

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM data
    -- convuled query goes here
)
WHERE NOT (column_1 IS NULL AND column_2 IS NULL AND column_3 IS NULL)
-- not all columns should be NULL
```

If you need to check for empty string instead of `NULL` just replace by `column_1 <> ''` etc...

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but as you said, I'm trying to do something that's not really part of the spec. Thanks.